# C++ changing reference of variable

Tags: c++

I'm fairly new to C++, coming from Java. I read up about pointers and such, but I just wanted to make sure I fully understand. Please forgive this elementary question. If I have this code:

```
vector<int> S = someVector;
vector<int> bestS = S;
S = anotherVector;
```

Is bestS reassigned to anotherVector? I wouldn't think so but since I read about how altering the dereferencing of pointer variables would change the underlying data for other pointers to that data, I'm a little unsure.

I guess I'm also asking, do object variable names behave as pointers?

Comment: Pointer behave as pointers.  `int* p = new int{5};`  versus `int i = 5;`  But in modern C++, smart pointers are suggested, `std::unique_ptr<int> p = std::make_unique<int>(5);`

Comment: Replace `vector<int>` with `int` or `double`.  The very same answers for `int` or `double` apply to `vector<int>`.  C++ doesn't change the rules of `=` just because the type looks "complex".  The value on the right side ot the `=` is assigned to the variable on the left side of the `=`.  IMO, this makes `=` act in a consistent manner, unlike `=` in Java, where you get a dual meaning for `=` depending on the types.

Answer (score 2):

> Is bestS reassigned to anotherVector?

No.  The way your example is written, `bestS` is a complete independent copy of `S`, so when you assign `anotherVector` to `S`, `S` becomes a new independent copy of `anotherVector`, clearing the previous data that was stored in `S` and copying data from `anotherVector` into `S`.  `bestS` is completely unaffected by anything you do to `S`.

Now, had you declared the variables (or at least `bestS`) as references, THEN it would behave as you are thinking:

```
vector<int> &bestS = S;
```

Then any changes to `S` are reflected in `bestS`, since `bestS` would just be an *alias* for `S`.

> I wouldn't think so but since I read about how altering the dereferencing of pointer variables would change the underlying data for other pointers to that data, I'm a little unsure.

There are no pointers in your example.

> do object variable names behave as pointers?

Only if you explicitly declare them as pointers, eg:

```
vector<int> *S = &someVector; // <-- S points to someVector
vector<int> *bestS = S; // <-- bestS also points to someVector
*S = anotherVector; // <-- changes someVector, changes can be seen via S and bestS
```

Comment: I think it's best to be careful here. The last `S = anotherVector` does not reassign `S` to be `anotherVector` in the same way as for C++ `int` or for Java `Object`. It's really just a method call: `S.operator=(anotherVector);`, a command to the object `S` to *become* a copy of the object `anotherVector`. The object that `S` refers to is not discarded and replaced. It's just that the object is told to dispose of all of its data and replace it with a copy of `anotherVector`'s.

Comment: To add on this answer, if you have a value type `T` (`std::vector<int>` in your example), then a reference to `T` would be written as `T&` (`std::vector<int>&`) and a pointer to `T` would be `T*` (std::vector<int>*)>.

Comment: So when you say "bestS is a complete independent copy of S", you are saying the underlying object gets copied?

Just want to make sure since the way I learned it in Java was something like `Array` isn't a primitive type (ie. so it is a reference type), and so doing what I posted would essentially act as a pointer?

Comment: When you type `S = anotherVector` the content of `anotherVector` is copied into `S`. What you posted has nothing to do with pointer as all your variable are value type.

Comment: So if it is a content copy, if I do: `S.add(1)` instead of reassigning `S` with `S = anotherVector`, would the changes affect `bestS`?

Comment: No `S` and `bestS` are two completely different element in your code snippet. Changing `S` doesn't affect `bestS` nor it affects `anotherVector`.

Comment: @bayesianpower Unlike Java, C++ lets you talk about objects: `std::vector<int> bestS = S;` is a *constructor call*, alternately written `std::vector<int> bestS(S);` and afterwards `bestS` denotes that new object, not a reference. There's no "underlying" object, `bestS` *is* the object. Now, `S` contains pointers to other objects (the `int`s), and whether the construction copies *those* "underlying objects" or only the pointers is "technically" up to the class itself. I say "technically" because the specification of `std::vector` mandates a deep copy, but you don't know that from the code.